# CAML Query with Date Range

Tags: caml-query, spsitedataquery

I'm writing an `SPSiteDataQuery` and I am having issues with the `Query` property. I need to return all results where the `Record_x0020_Yr_x0020_End_x0020_Date` is between 12/31 of the current year and 90 days prior.

Example: If I ran this query now, I should get all items where the date lies between 9/31/2011-12/31/2011. If I ran the query at any point next year, I should get 9/31/2012-12/31/2012. Here's what I have thus far:

```
query.Query = string.Format(@"
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Record_x0020_Yr_x0020_End_x0020_Date' />
        <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>{0}</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>", new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 31).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

This gives me all those whose date is on the end of the year, but how do I add the range?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Download a [CAML query builder tool such as this one by U2U](http://www.u2u.be/Tools/wincamlquerybuilder/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) to help you get the syntax right.

Using that tool this is what I get for Start Date >= 1/Jan/2011 AND StartDate <= 31/Dec/2011 - you can adapt this to your list columns and date range.

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <And>
      <Geq>
        <FieldRef Name="StartDate" />
          <Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2011-01-01T15:55:52Z</Value>
      </Geq>
      <Leq>
        <FieldRef Name="StartDate" />
        <Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2011-12-31T15:56:29Z</Value>
      </Leq>
    </And>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan. The concept of trying to think of a SQL query in CAML was just confusing me. Shortly after posting, I came up with exactly what you have, except for the <And>. Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that columns included in your <Where> will probably need to be an indexed column within Sharepoint in order for the query to work, especially if your record count is over the ListView threshold.

Answer (score -4):

Check this out:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/076c57b1-a780-4b86-b00b-849fa8789318

your two dates:

```
DateTime lastDay = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 31);
DateTime dtThreeMonthsPrior = lastDay.AddMonths(-3);
```

Also, in your question you mentioned date like 9/31 which is invalid because 9th month has only 30 days.. lol