# CAML query how to change to get a range from a date start to date end

Tags: development

In the code sample below, how should I change it to take a date range in a CAML query?

```
    string FullQueryUrlap = "<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Geq><And><Leq><FieldRef Name='{2}' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>{3}</Value></Leq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Nazwisko' /><Value Type='Note'>{4}</Value></Eq></And></And></Where>";
        string dateISO1 = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(e.Day.Date.ToLocalTime());
        Convert.ToDateTime(dateISO1);

        int spacja = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.IndexOf(" ");

        var queryPoszczegolnyUrlop = new SPQuery();
        queryPoszczegolnyUrlop.Query = String.Format(FullQueryUrlap, "DataPoc", dateISO1, "DataKon", dateISO1, DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToUpper().Substring(0, spacja));
        queryPoszczegolnyUrlop.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='DataPoc' /><FieldRef Name='DataKon' />";
        queryPoszczegolnyUrlop.ViewFieldsOnly = true;

        SPListItemCollection listaDniUrlopow = witryna1.Lists["ListaUrlopow2012"].GetItems(queryPoszczegolnyUrlop);

        DateTime dataPoc= new DateTime();
        DateTime dataKon = new DateTime();

        DateTime theDate = e.Day.Date;

        for (int interator = 0; interator < listaDniUrlopow.Count; interator++)
        {
            SPListItem item = listaDniUrlopow[interator];
            dataPoc = Convert.ToDateTime(item["DataPoc"]);
            dataKon = Convert.ToDateTime(item["DataKon"]);
```

The debbuger told me that `listaDniUrlopow.Count` have got 0 elements. Please help. When I giving that query string `FullQueryUrlap = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Nazwisko' /><Value Type='Text'>{2}</Value></Eq></And></Where>";` it count me one element which show "dataPoc" value.

Comment: This has been asked and answered here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15770/caml-query-with-date-range

Comment: I write as You told, but it doesn't work. Please look my answer

Answer (score 1):

Gt - greater operator

Lt - less operator

Look at [this link](http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/writing-caml-queries-for-retrieving-list-items-from-a-sharepoint-list) for more information.

Code sample for you, you can use Geq - greater of equal and Leq - less or equal instead, depending of your case.

```
<And>
    <Gt><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Gt>
    <Lt><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Lt>
</And>
```

Comment: Use CAML Query Builder to make queries. It is for 2003 and 2007 SharePoint, but also works fine with SharePoint 2010 http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx

Comment: I'm using this, but that is need a parameters to send start, and end days.