# How to find out how many documents have been uploaded to a library/site in the last month?

Tags: document, library, reporting

I am trying to get some analytical information on how many documents are being added to a particular site or library by my company users.

Does anyone know how I can find out this kind of information? There is nothing in the site web/site collection analytic reports that gives me what I need.

Comment: What type of information do you need?

Comment: I find solution on site..
Click [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15770/caml-query-with-date-range)

Answer (score 1):

You can generate **CAML** query on Document Library and fetch last month uploaded Document data. This is the easiest way to get the list of document.

--> Question : Where should you display this data?

--> Is there any requirement of generating a report of last month uploaded document?

For more reference :

http://platinumdogs.me/2009/07/21/querying-document-libraries-or-pulling-teeth-with-caml/

```
<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name='Created' />     
</ViewFields>    
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Created' />
        <Value Type='DateTime'>"Your Date Or month"</Value>
    </Eq>    
</Where>
```

Answer (score 1):

If doing custom development follow these simple steps

```
public static int getItemsInLastMonth(ref SPWeb web,string listName)
{
        SPList list = web.TryGetList(listName);
        if(list != null) {
             SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
             query.Query = "<Where>"+
                             "<Eq>"+
                                  "<FieldRef Name='Created' />"+
                                  "<Value Type='DateTime'>+ <Today> +</Value>"+
                             "</Eq>"+    
                          "</Where>";
            query.ViewFields = "<ViewFields>"+
                                   "<FieldRef Name='ID' />"+     
                                "</ViewFields>";
            SPListItemCollection collection = list.GetItems(query);

            if(collection != null){
                return collection.count;
             }
       }
}
```

This will give you total items created in last month. Similar you can do for document library also, and do it in client side coding.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a library, you can just use a view without resorting to development. Just create a new View and make the filter into the Created equals the date of one month ago.

- Go to the List you want to view
- Go to the top where it says "Create View"
- Enter in a name
- Create a filter like it says below

[image]