# In SharePoint 2010, is there a way to display the total number of items that were submitted for the current month?

Tags: javascript, web-part, jquery, data-view-web-part, jquery-ui

Example:  I entered 10 items in a list this month and now I would like to see the number 10 display in another web part in another page.  I don't want to see the individual items I just want to display something like this:

Current Month submission = 10

Each item has a different date time stamped on a custom field.

Comment: Do you want SharePoint OOTB solution or custom code?

Comment: I prefer OOTB but if custom code is easier I can do that as well.

Comment: I should have elaborated a little more than what I did.  I am creating a splash page.  I was tasked to create a little web part about 205 Pixels wide that would display abstract information from another SharePoint survey list.  They want to display the number of submissions that were completed during the current month.  The display on the web part will be as follows:  "Current Month Count 10 Submissions"  it is just counting the number of items submitted for the current month.

Comment: Can you use JavaScript to get the data and render it on the splash page?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Group BY in a view:

1) Create a calculated column to obtain the month

2) Create a view and group by the calculated column. Use option "collapsed groups"

Comment: Thank You, this works but it is only part of the solution.

Comment: Yes because you can not order by the rank.

Answer (score 0):

There is Total section in list view section, but you would need entering current month in view filter and there will be items in view...

So, there is simple custom Javascript solution with SharePoint JSOM:

1. Use JS to query SharePoint for list items by CAML:
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/office/jj163201.aspx
   "Retrieve items from a list" section.
   You should set date start and date end variables and use them in your CAML, here is the nice post: [CAML Query with Date Range](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15770/caml-query-with-date-range)
2. Use `collListItem.get_count();` to get items count and then add value to your HTML.

Hope this helps, welcome to ask any questions.